# Prove Using Definition that the Sequence $\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n}+2}$ Diverges to Infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Formally, a sequence $x_n$ diverges to infinity whenever for all $M>0$ there exists $N(M)$ such that $n>N(M)$ implies $x_n>M$.

Prove formally, using the definition, that the following sequence diverges to infinity:
\begin{equation}
x_n=\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n}+2}
\end{equation}

Proof. Let $M>0$. Take $N(M)=?$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M>0$ be given. We require

$$\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n}+2} >M \ \forall n>N$$

We know that

$$\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n}+2} > \frac{n}{\sqrt n+ \sqrt n} = \frac{\sqrt n}{2} \mbox{for } n > 4$$

So take

$$N=4M^2$$

and we have

$$\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n}+2}>M \ \forall n>N=max\{4, 4M^2 \} $$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** You want for all $n >N(M)$ to have:
$$\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n}+2} >M $$
Solve this inequality for $n$.

Or easier, you can observe that
$$\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n}+2}> \frac{n-4}{\sqrt{n}+2}=\frac{(\sqrt{n}-2)(\sqrt{n}+2)}{\sqrt{n}+2}$$
and if you make this last term greater than $M$ you are done.

Comment: Awesome! Just choose $N=(M+2)^2$. Awesome idea; thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

$$x_n\ge \frac{n-4}{\sqrt{n}+2}=\sqrt{n}-2 > M$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Just take $N=(M+2)^2$ and it works. Awesome - thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The standard thing to do is multiply top and bottom by (something like) the conjugate of the bottom. So:
$$
\frac{n+1}{\sqrt n+2}
=
\frac{(n+1)(\sqrt n - 2)}{n-4}\,.
$$
Now, as long as $n\ge9$, you get $(n+1)\big/(n-4)\le2$, while $\sqrt n-2$ gets big. That should do it for you, I think.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$n=t^2 \implies \dfrac{\sqrt{n}+2}{n+1}=\dfrac{t+2}{t^2+1}=\dfrac{t}{t^2+1}+\dfrac{2}{t^2+1}$

$t\to \infty \implies \dfrac{t}{t^2+1}+\dfrac{2}{t^2+1} \to0$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation}
x_n=\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n}+2}
\end{equation}

term by term

$$\begin{align}\left[\sqrt{n+2} < \sqrt{n}+2\right]&\implies\left[\frac{n+1 \color{red}{+1-1}}{\sqrt{n+2}}>\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n}+2}\right] \\
&\implies \sqrt{n+2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}} > x_n \\
&\implies a_n > x_n
\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}
\left[n+1>n-4\right] &\implies \left[\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n}+2} >\frac{n-4}{\sqrt{n}+2}\right] \\
&\implies x_n >\sqrt{n}-2 \\
&\implies x_n > b_n
\end{align}$$

by the squeeze theorem:

$\lim _{n \to \infty} x_n \to \infty$ if and only if $\lim _{n \to \infty} a_n \to \infty$ and $\lim _{n \to \infty} b_n \to \infty$